# Qt GUI is not behaving normally on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt

I have created an application in Qt Necessitas. When I start it on my Android device I have a GUI which is very different from what I see in Qt Creator.

For example: I have created spacing between a label and textbox and when I start it as a desktop app everything is okay. But when I port it to Android it seems it's not working. And then my textbox is smaller than in the normal GUI in Creator, as are the buttons and so on.

What might cause this and what can I do about it?

And one more thing: I have a problem with resizing the app size to the max of device window. But I get error about loading fullscreen FALSE.

I have started Qt Mobile application. Everything is done in mainwindow. So I have put all commands on my mainwindow. I don't know what to do. If you need a specific file please tell me, so I can post it here.

Comment: Any idea?? I really don't know why is this happening?

Comment: I can't make you screenshot on PC, because I can see in QT Creator my design perfectly as I want it to be. Problem is when I port it to android. Everything is small, font's are different, space between elements is gone and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your Mainwindow smaller and play with sizes. maybe the resolution you are using is not supported by the device.

Comment: No, I have tried everything. Then I realized that it is better to use QML for making gui. And that solved my problem. Btw. problem is I think in predefined sizes that are made for android. Anyway problem is solved, but thank you for trying.